# Shell : How to get pid given apart of its name string

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I've this running java process:

```
testuser 37126     1  0  2018 ?        01:56:24 java -jar backend76465465.jar -XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow --spring.profiles.active=server
```

I want to dynamically get its pid based on :

- a part of its name: "backend"

  (which is the fix part "backend") ,
- the other part : 76465465 would always change
  i ve tried this :

  ```
  ps -eaf | awk '$NF~"backend" {print $2}'
  ```

and this :

```
ps -eaf | grep java | awk '$NF~"backend" {print $2}'
```

but it still give me empty results .

**Suggestions ?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried to use `ps aux | grep backend`?

Answer (score 3):

Try `pgrep` , it will return the pid of the matched process :

```
pgrep -f backend
```